# Displaying data in GridView based on Label.Text condition

Tags: c#, html, sql, asp.net, session

I'm trying to display in a `GridView` data from my **Customers** database table, filtered by user's email. I tried to set the condition in my sql query as follows:

`Select * from customers where cid= profile_label.Text`

but the `adapt.Fill(dt)` caused an error and the code couldn't compile. Any advice/help will be highly appreciated!

This is my code that executes when the page is loaded:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
               profile_Label.Text = Session["Profile"].ToString();
                Object pro = profile_Label.Text;

        //Connection String from web.config File  
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ShowData();
            }
        }

   string cs =   ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
         SqlConnection con;
         SqlDataAdapter adapt;
         DataTable dt;
```

Here is the snippet of my code (script and c#)

This is my c# code containing the method to display the data based on an sql query

```
 protected void ShowData()
        {
            dt = new DataTable();
            con = new SqlConnection(cs);
            con.Open();


           adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from customers", con);

        adapt.Fill(dt);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)

            {
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
            con.Close();
        }
```

And this is my script code:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    CellPadding="6" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit"  
    OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" Height="226px" Width="1172px"> 

              <Columns>  
            <asp:TemplateField>  
                <ItemTemplate>  
                    <asp:Button ID="btn_Edit" runat="server" Text="Edit" 
           CommandName="Edit" />  
                </ItemTemplate>  
                <EditItemTemplate>  
                    <asp:Button ID="btn_Update" runat="server" Text="Update" 
            CommandName="Update"/>  
                    <asp:Button ID="btn_Cancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" 
             CommandName="Cancel"/>  
                </EditItemTemplate>  
            </asp:TemplateField>  
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer ID">  
                <ItemTemplate>  
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_CID" runat="server" 
                     Text='<%#Eval("CID") %>'></asp:Label>  

                </ItemTemplate>  
            </asp:TemplateField>  
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name">  
                <ItemTemplate>  
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_FName" runat="server" 
                   Text='<%#Eval("FName") %>'></asp:Label>  
                </ItemTemplate>  
                <EditItemTemplate>  
                    <asp:TextBox ID="fname_txt" 
                      runat="server"Text='<%#Eval("FName") %>'>
                  </asp:TextBox>  
                </EditItemTemplate>  
            </asp:TemplateField>  
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name">  
                <ItemTemplate>  
     <asp:Label ID="lbl_Lname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Lname") %>'>
                   </asp:Label>  
                </ItemTemplate>  
                <EditItemTemplate>  
    <asp:TextBox ID="lname_txt" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Lname") %>'>
              </asp:TextBox>  
                </EditItemTemplate>  
            </asp:TemplateField> 

                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date of Birth">  
                <ItemTemplate>  
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_DOB" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("DOB") %>'>
               </asp:Label>  
                </ItemTemplate>  
                <EditItemTemplate>  
         <asp:TextBox ID="dob_txt" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("DOB") %>'>
               </asp:TextBox>  
                </EditItemTemplate>  
            </asp:TemplateField>  

               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email">  
                <ItemTemplate>  
       <asp:Label ID="lbl_email" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Email") %>'>
               </asp:Label>  
                </ItemTemplate>  
                <EditItemTemplate>  
<asp:TextBox ID="email_txt" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("email") %>'>
             </asp:TextBox>  
                </EditItemTemplate>  
            </asp:TemplateField> 
               </columns>
                 </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: @AbZy I stated the error I get in the question when I write an sql query with the where condition, however when I run the program it simply displays all the data in my customers table

Answer (score 1):

You can use parameters in your query and replace them with the correct value.

```
string query = "Select * from customers where cid = @cid";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection))
{
    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@cid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = profile_label.Text;

    try
    {
        adapter.Fill(dt);
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: where will this code be placed? in the page load method? Plus I want data to be displayed from the customer's table based on the user's email which will be in the session

Comment: Running your answer gives in errors, the first being <b> profile_label.Text </b> does not exist in the current context.

Answer (score 0):

Simply the answer was to directly place the session into the SQL query as follows without storing the session value in another variable

```
  String query = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE Email ='"+ Session["Profile"]+"'";
```